# Is it possible to give multiple potion effects with one command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to give multiple potion effects with one command block?

For example, I have command block hooked up to a pressure plate and I want it to give a player *Slowness 255* and *Jump Boost 150*, effectively holding them in place for a set period of time or until an `/effect @p clear command` is run on them.

Is there anyway to do this without having to use more than 1 command block for both effects?

Comment: May I just point out how wonderfully [my proposed logical operators](http://minecraft.iqandreas.com/blog/suggestions/logical-operators-in-command-blocks/) would fit in in these cases?

Answer (score 2):

You can't execute two commands from within one command block. The only halfways acceptable solution is to spawn in another command block with a preloaded command, such as this:

```
/setblock ~ ~2 ~ minecraft:command_block 0 destroy {Command:/say Hi}
```

[source](http://www.planetminecraft.com/forums/post2536372.html#p2536372)

Where you'd need to replace /say Hi with your command.